# how to match a list of parameters in java with regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to match lists like:

```
a = 9, b=5 , c = 15
```

The values can be also of type double, string, char and boolean, or a previous variable (for example, `a=b`). I've tried to arrange the following regular expression

```
([A-Za-z0-9](=)?(,)?)|((=)?,\s*\d+)*
```

but no success achieved so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex `([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)` :

## regex demo

**matches** :

```
a = 9 
b=5
c = 15
a=b
b= true
s = false
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to matche a list like this for example :

```
a = 9 , b=5 , c = 15 , a=b , b= true , s = false
```

then you can use a regex like this `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*,?\s*)*`

## regex demo 2

in jave you can use :

```
boolean m = "a = 9 , b=5 , c = 15 , a=b , b= true , s = false".
                matches("^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s*=\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s*,?\\s*)*");//true
```

Comment: I think you're missing the list, OP seems to want to match `a  = 1,  b=3`, according to their regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Solution 1**

```
(\s*[A-Za-z0-9]\s*=\s*\S*(,)?)+
```

If you want to capture all the elements in the list then:

**Solution 2**

```
 ((\s*[A-Za-z0-9]\s*=\s*\S*(,)?)+)
```

YCF_L solutions looks good also except for one small variation:

^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*=\s* **[a-zA-Z0-9]+**\s*,?\s*)*

The second part ignores the fact that you could have a double value.
It will still match, but if you were to capture the values as in **Solution 2** above but using the YCF_L solution then the decimal portion will be dropped.

Here is great link on capturing repeated groups:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html